# List Objects from AWS S3 bucket using ASP.NET

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket which has multiple folders. I want to list S3 objects from specific sub folders. For example my folder structure is: Folder1/Download, Folder1/Upload. Here, I want the objects only from Folder1/Download and not the upload. The function that I'm using is:

```
public void GetFTPFilesAWS(long ID)
        {
            AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client("", "", Amazon.Region);
            ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
            {
                BucketName = "",
                //Prefix = "Download",
                //Delimiter = "/"
            };
            var practiceFolderName = "Practice_" + ID;
            string[] businessClaim = { "Folder1/Download/", "Folder2/Download/",};
            foreach (string s in businessClaim)
            {
                _ = practiceFolderName + s;
            }
            ListObjectsResponse response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(request);


        }
```

I'm getting every object from my bucket using this and when I'm trying to use the prefix and delimiter it's not working.

Comment: You need to specify the prefix in the request - yours is commented out - `//Prefix = "Download",` so it will return all items.

Comment: When I'm giving the prefix no object is being returned, I'm assuming since my prefix is in the middle of the path, maybe that's why? can you help here please

Comment: "Searching by prefix limits the results to only those keys that begin with the specified prefix" - s3 doesnt support partial matching of a prefix, prefix must be from bucket root. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html)